# How to fix no variable echoed in PHP Post request?

Tags: php, html

I am setting up a new website and want to be able to gather user input on the checkout page and echo the user input on the confirmation page. How do I perform this operation?

This is using html and php. In the past, I've tried using POST method, isset, $_Request functions.

This is the code for Confirmationpage.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Confirmation page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Confirmation page</h1>
    <h2>Order Confirmed!</h2>
    <?php
      // define variables and set to empty values
      $fName = $lName = $email = $phoneNumber = "";

      if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

        $fName = $_POST["fName"];
        $lName = $_POST["lName"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $phoneNumber = $_POST["phoneNumber"];
        echo $fName . " " . $lName;
        echo $email;
      }

      function test_input($data) {

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;

      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code for Checkoutpage.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkout page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Checkout page</h1>
        <form action="Confirmationpage.html" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <input type="number" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"> 
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected the first name, last name and email to be echoed in the confirmation page however the actual result is not outputting the first name, last name and email.

Comment: The Confirmation page outputs: Confirmation page and Order Confirmed!

Comment: if you're going to have php codes in your file, at least turn them as `.php` files, the problem is because you're still using `.html` files

Comment: and at least install a local server for you to test on

Comment: Ooh! I should go try that now.

Comment: Yes! I am using XAMPP.

Comment: I have changed them into .php files but it still doesn't work.

Comment: try to write `die;` after them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
echo $fName . " " . $lName;
echo '<br>';
echo $email;die;
```

> Keep this in mind: your file should be `.php`

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: is it `.php` page?

Comment: Actually I got an output. This is the output: '; echo $email;die; echo $fName . " " . $lName; echo $email; } function test_input($data) { $data = trim($data); $data = stripslashes($data); $data = htmlspecialchars($data); return $data; } ?>

Comment: First I put the die in the confirmationpage.php but then I think that might be wrong I think so I put it into the confirmationpage.html and I got the output I posted above.

Comment: All I did was change the checkoutpage.html: <form action="Confirmationpage.php" method="POST">

Comment: I don't know what page is supposed to be php and what page supposed to be html haha.

Comment: @DwarfChampion make them all `.php`, so you can expand upon them using PHP in the future without having to refactor every link in your application when you want to use a php variable in an HTML file.

Comment: Please use php file instead of html. Rename the file name Confirmationpage.html => Confirmationpage.php and also change the file name in form action. If you have not installed php on your system. Please install php first and try again.